# Using SoftLayer API to retrieve VM Network information

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to retrieve the private default gateway and subnet mask through the SoftLayer API.  I can see this information at control.softlayer.com but I'd like to retrieve it through the API.  I have tried all the network related methods in the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest service but haven't been able to find this information.  What method should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/getBackendNetworkComponents?objectMask=mask[primarySubnet[gateway,netmask]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$vsiId** with your own information

**Note:** Just in case, if you wish to get the same information for public network, you should use **getFrontendNetworkComponents** instead of **getBackendNetworkComponents** in the request

References:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBackendNetworkComponents](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBackendNetworkComponents)
- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getFrontendNetworkComponents](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getFrontendNetworkComponents)
- [Object Masks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks)

Comment: That works!  Why does this information not appear when leaving the mask off?

Comment: This is due to this is an additional information from the network component (In this case from the primarySubnet), and the only way to get this is using a mask. You can see in this link: [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component), the basic information retrieved for the component, but you can get more information displayed in **Relational & Count Properties** section, to access them, you should use an **object mask**